# How can i use fluid template on command line in typo3 flow

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-flow

I am trying to use fluid templates on command line controller on typo3 flow. The documentation is not full. How can i tweak it and solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not meant to work, but if you really need this you can instanciate a Fluid StandaloneView, render it and give the result to the CommandController::output() method.